# Cant get active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes & skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I cant seem to get skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes or active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes working in my Rails 5 App

in my application.rb I have

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

And in my model I have

```
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:start_date, :end_date]
```

Yet when the stat date and end date are sent back to the client as JSON, they are always converted into the clients timezone. I dont want that as I need to show the client the server time.

Why is this not working? Do I need to do something else to ensure that the start_date and end_date in my model, do not get translated to the users time zone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is occurred due to rails have several pitfalls. Most importantly because Time.now and Time.current are completely different things.

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin' # Your local time zone
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

This are fields present within **application.rb**, make things happen for all your model's time related attributes.

For example -
if you didn't mention any time_zone then it will take 'UTC' by defaults

```
post = Post.create
post.created_at # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 06:43:08 UTC +00:00 

Time.current # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 06:43:35 UTC +00:00 
Time.now # => 2019-04-22 12:13:40 +0530
```

In your database and Time.current shows the 'UTC' format but Time.now is picking your local timezone.

Now if you change time_zone,

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```

Then,

```
post = Post.create
post.created_at # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 08:45:48 CEST +02:00 

Time.current # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 08:46:05 CEST +02:00 
Time.now # => 2019-04-22 12:16:00 +0530
```

Now in your database, *created_at* value stored with 'UTC' time zone but when you retrieve that field it shows in set time_zone format means in 'Berlin'. But still your Time.now is in your local timezone.

Now as per your question I am using **skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes**, and changed my model with time_zone is 'Berlin'

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:created_at]
end
```

Then,

```
post = Post.create
post.created_at # => 2019-04-22 06:56:31 UTC 

Time.current # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 08:56:53 CEST +02:00 
Time.now # => 2019-04-22 12:26:46 +0530
```

As per **skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes** method it's skip for that attributes,  when I retried the attribute - created_at it shows it in 'UTC' format instead of my set time_zone 'Berlin', working as expected.

So this could be helpful for you to understand and check your setting before set it in JSON.

For more information you can refer this link - 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

https://makandracards.com/makandra/46009-working-with-or-without-time-zones-in-rails-applications